# Can I run a Java FX and a Swing UI in the same process?

Tags: multithreading, swing, javafx, javafx-8

I have bigger multi-threaded UI application with a lot of background calculations&io tasks. There is a new component coming up with an UI I'd like to write in javafx.

Now my question is, can I run a swing UI on the AWT-Dispatcher Thread and a Javafx UI on the FX Application Thread in the same process or does this have any bad consequences?

Thanks for any answer!

Answer (score 1):

You can. It's supposed to make the migration from Swing to JavaFX easier. However, you need to consider the threading as you guessed.

Here's an article with more information about it: [Integrating JavaFX into Swing Applications](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/fx_swing.htm#JFXIP561)